# Is it possible to get list of Voice-Recognition-Languages in Azure Translator Speech API?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

In Azure Cognitive Service, Is it possible to get 'Short-form Voice Recognition Languages'(https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/languages.aspx) from this language API(http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/languages.html )?

I realized Azure Translator Speech API can recognize Korean. But language API doesn't return Korean as speech supported language, only tts.

I've tried Translator Speech API(http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/speech-translate.html) Websocket Connection under the following parameters, from = hi(Hindi), to = en. The connection returned 404. But from = ko, to = en , the websocket connection returns 200 and it can recognize Korean Conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Korean is currently not a supported language for conversational translations (speech-to-speech).